PHP encrypted Code uploaded in cpanel and changed users passwords to login in cpanel
Yesterday i received email, that my cpanel password changed, and contact my Provider and they send me new pass, but today same thing happened. Then i realized something went wrong. so i decided to reset pass and monitor whats going on, after few minutes i see there were 5 new php files added some day ago and the one with encrypted Php code executed on specific time, and i noticed at that time password was changed.
I tired to read other codes written in php, and checked many times how it might possible to upload code in public domain folder, there is no option to upload any files on public domain, so how it could be possible.

This is how it started ".base64_decode("JXNsMmh3bjBrLQolZzh..................6000 plus then ended k7ID8+")); ?> like this.

Relevant: How do I deal with a compromised server?

There are a number of ways someone could potentially have uploaded a script to your public folder - e.g. a permissions flaw in your filesystem configuration, so that the folder is writable by other scripts, code injection vulnerabilities, or someone just got access to your FTP credentials, etc

maybe, but he used a ftp git repo, and i don't know how that code help him to upload his code and even he run shell as well, after approach git repo owner he said maybe hacker access the server root and after that he target each domain.

Could be. There's nothing we can tell you just from staring at some obfuscated code. Speak to the owners of the server if you think that might have happened
